# Azure Notification Hub and UWP app with code-signing certificate (desktop bridge)

Tags: wpf, uwp, push-notification, azure-notificationhub, desktop-bridge

I have a desktop bridge app (WPF) which package is signed with a code-signing certificate, how should I configure Azure Notification Hub to receive push notifications from this app?

Azure requires a Package SID and a Security Key that I haven't because the app is not distributed on the store.

Answer (score 1):

Official answer from Microsoft:

> Sadly it is not possible.
>   Azure notification hub requires the Package SID and a Security Key. You could get the Package SID and a Security Key even if your app is not published to the MS store.
>   But if you create the package using the code-signing certificate, the author in the manifest changes and notifications no longer arrive

Answer (score 0):

> Azure requires a Package SID and a Security Key that I haven't because the app is not distributed on the store.

To make the Azure Notification Hub send notification notification successfully, the Package SID and a Security Key is necessary. You could get the Package SID and a Security Key even if your app is not published to the MS store.

Please see the [Create an app in Windows Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification#create-an-app-in-windows-store) tutorial. In the step 3, click the 'Live Service Site', it will navigate directly to the Application Registration Portal. Sign in to your Microsoft account and select your application name, then you will see the Package SID and a Security Key on the page.

After that, right-click the packaged app project, select Store, and then select Associate App with the Store. You need to associate your project with the app that you created in the Windows Dev Center.

Comment: I can do this and it works, but if I create the package using the code-signing certificate, the author in the manifest changes and notifications no longer arrive (Azure fails to send).

Comment: If so, it's impossible.